# Convert string array to jagged array in java

Tags: java

I have a 1D array of values and I need help separating these values in groups using a jagged array in order to do a series of calculations.
e.g.

```
int array []={1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}
```

I want to separate and assign the first 4 in one array, the next 3 in another array and then the last 3 in a third array. I was hoping to get an output like this in my code.

```
int [][] x = new int [3][];

x[0] = new int [4];
x[0] = {1 2 3 4};

x[1] = new int [3];
x[1] = {5 6 7};

x[2] = new int [3];
x[2] = {8 9 10};
```

Is there any other way of making this jagged array using a flexible for loop and for me to split this array in M number of groups or N number of values in a group?
I tried accessing those values using substring() but I'm not quite sure how to go on about this or if I'm doing this right.

```
 for( int i=0; i<x.length; i++) { 
 x [i]= array.substring (0,3);
 x [i]=array.substring (4,6);
 x [i]=array.substring(7,9);
 }
```

I'm only new to programming but this code is clearly wrong, but can you you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)?

```
x[0] = new int[4];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, x[0], 0, 4);
x[1] = new int[3];
System.arraycopy(array, 4, x[1], 0, 3);
x[2] = new int[3];
System.arraycopy(array, 7, x[2], 0, 3);
```

If not, your question is maybe a bit misleading. Where should the sizes of the sub-arrays come from?

Or is this more what you want?

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int xLength = 3;
int[][] x = new int[xLength][];
int arrayLength = array.length;
int remainders = arrayLength % xLength;
int subArrayLength = arrayLength / xLength;
int arrayIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    int adjustedSubArrayLength = subArrayLength;
    if (remainders > 0)
    {
        adjustedSubArrayLength++;
        remainders--;
    }
    x[i] = new int[adjustedSubArrayLength];
    System.arraycopy(array, arrayIndex, x[i], 0, adjustedSubArrayLength);
    arrayIndex = adjustedSubArrayLength;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hence you can't change the size of an array in Java after it has been created, you need new arrays where you can store your data. There is a static `System` function, which allows you to copy a specific length of an array called: `System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int[][] to2dArray(int[] array, int... colSizes) {
    int[][] result = new int[colSizes.length][];
    for (int i = 0, start = 0; i < colSizes.length; start += colSizes[i++])
        result[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, start, start + colSizes[i]);
    return result;
}
```

And

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(to2dArray(array, 4, 3, 3)));
// -> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```